# Resources to get started on the manga/anime universe

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In MetaJLU, there is a [list of resources for learning Japanese](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese).

I thought this could be a good reference for something we might do here: create a list of works of reference that may introduce new users into the manga/anime world. This could go from technical works (that provide technical and theoretical details of manga/anime, as well as history of these media) to more informal works that would provide general views into Japanese/otaku culture ([Peter Carey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Carey_%28novelist%29)'s [Wrong About Japan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrong_about_Japan) comes to mind). It could also, if this kind of questions were to be considered on-topic, contain works that are concerned with the making of anime/manga.

This is just a general idea, but I think it could turn out to be a good thing. Leave your thoughts.

Comment: I mentioned this in Area51 but I think this would be a good way to link to legal/official streams as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a very good idea. We have **[reference questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/871050)** as well.

Only I don't think it should be done on the meta site, but on the main site, and as a community-wiki. This is a question regarding anime/manga, not about the anime/manga site, therefore I suggest we open it on the main site.

Comment: Ok, so after some discussion regarding the contents on such a list and how it should be operated, someone will create it.

Comment: Since moderators only have that power to make nice CW, I think we should group the resources in Meta for now, and then we can move them to the Main site.

Comment: By the way, whether the resources go to the Main site or stay on Meta is quite indifferent. But having them on the main site will make them more searchable. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would propose the following categories for a resource list here:

- Legal online (English) anime sources
- Legal online (English) manga sources
- Links to anime/manga import companies
- Books about Anime/Manga as art or culture
- Indexing sites (this might be tricky... as most are fansub indexers... allowed or not?)
- Major Japanese (language) anime/manga fansites (questionable...)