# How should we handle posts containing anime & manga resources?

Tags: discussion

Back in private beta, we discussed [a proposal](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/156/274) on whether we should allow a limited set of "resource" posts to be available, just like [meta JLU's](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/756/3035). StackOverflow has [some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/1438733) as well. The purpose of these resource posts is twofold: to help users find useful resources that other community members use, and also to allow us to redirect people who ask disallowed questions (like recommendations) to resources where those are valid.

The proposal was never discussed thoroughly nor concluded, but it is one that should be decided upon by the community. Thus, I've set up this poll so that the community can have a say in how this will be handled. There are three options:

**Option 1: Allow the posts on Meta**

1. The posts will be allowed on the meta Anime & Manga site.
2. These posts will be **locked** or **wiki'd and protected** (depending on context).
3. Users who ask questions which are covered by the resources will have questions closed as usual, then get a comment linking them to said post.

**Option 2: Allow the posts on Main**

1. The posts will be allowed on the main Q&A portion of the Anime & Manga site.
2. These posts will be **locked** or **wiki'd and protected** (depending on context).
3. Users who ask questions which are covered by the resources will have questions closed as a duplicate of the resource question.

**Option 3: Disallow the posts**

1. There will be no resource posts allowed on Meta or Main.

To vote, please **upvote the answer whose option you agree with**. You should **not** downvote other answers, as **downvotes will not be counted**.

Any additional points can be edited into or commented on their respective option post.

Comment: I don't think resource requests should belong on the main site. Often times these types of questions are not constructive or not a real question, because they don't fit SE's Q&A model. Often times asking for a solution to a problem is often times better than a reference. By allowing these, we have to make the effort to maintain these lists and make sure they are up-to-date. We also have to make sure that the given subject matter is canonical. Trying to maintain these questions as they come along may require a lot of effort from both users moderators and can be quite time consuming.

Comment: If we do allow them we are better off letter users request a resource in meta on a specific topic and getting together and compiling a list we can all agree upon.

Comment: @Krazer The "locked post" reason explicitly states "*but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site*" (see: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9033/1438733)). I think it's just better to isolate the knowledge and resources to the main site because that's where people will expect them.

Comment: By locking it you are essentially admitting that it's not a good question for this site. I personally think that this will set an bad precedence, especially if we allow it on the main site. It's best to keep off-topic questions such as resource requests to a minimum so we don't lose ourselves trying to QC and maintain them.

Comment: @Krazer I disagree. By locking it you're saying it's *not the type of question that we want more of* on the site. I don't think those types of questions will hurt us in the long run (or even the short run).

Comment: By locking the question, you're preventing it from being maintained by anyone except moderators. Which kinda kills the point doesn't it? Resource questions on other sites aren't locked. They won't be locked here either.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha [Some are](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9033/1438733). [Some are not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/1438733).

Comment: Locking the question is unacceptable since it prevents any form of maintenance, which is often necessary. Plus it's stupid to create questions just to lock them. Locking a question basically says "we wish we could get rid of this but we can't because it used to be allowed and it generated useful responses". It's called a "historic lock" for a reason.

Comment: I think I agree with @Krazer on this one. If we're going to allow these at all, it should be on Meta. Frequently updating a meta post is not anywhere near as disruptive as a main site post. It also eliminates the incentive for new users to post and makes it more clear that this is a community undertaking rather than an invitation for everyone to add their own favorite answer. Plus, in my view, the questions are on topic for meta, but they aren't really about anime so they don't belong on main.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vote this up for **Option 2: Allow the posts on Main**.

Comment: I cast my own vote for **Option 2**.

Comment: Note that for it to be successful, the resource post needs to be useful enough to actually be maintained.

Answer (score 4):

Vote this up for **Option 1: Allow the posts on Meta**.

Comment: Meta is a place to ask about the site, it's not a place to seek information about anime or manga, that's what the main site is there for.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this doesn't understand that this is a poll.  You're only supposed to upvote the option you prefer, not downvote the other ones.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha This isn't really about "information about anime/manga" rather "information about information about anime/manga". Seems pretty meta to me, quite literally. :)

Comment: @atlantiza: No, the meta is about *the site*, [anime.se], *this site*, and not anything else. That's my opinion.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Right, but the site isn't about information about information about anime/manga. If you don't think it should go on meta then it doesn't belong anywhere on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Vote this up for **Option 3: Disallow the posts**.