# Are discussions/questions about YouTubers on anime stuff considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Are discussions/questions about *YouTubers on anime stuff*, say, Chibi Reviews, considered on-topic?

Answer (score 6):

Unless the YouTubers are also someone who is working in the anime/manga/(insert media) industry, **they may be considered as fandom and thus tend to be off-topic.** It's probably analogous to asking about *someone* who writes an article about anime & manga on Anime News Network.

On the other hand, if the questions are about one of the videos produced by YouTubers and about anime/manga, then they are possibly on-topic with the videos used as a reference. Note that in this case, the creator (YouTuber) is not really relevant though.

Related: [Are questions about what happened to/in/about specific anime/manga sites or communities considered on-topic?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/2516) (substitute "site/community" with "people")