# Citing YouTube videos - valid approach?

Tags: discussion, references

Can we use YouTube videos as references, especially Anituber videos in the answers? YouTubers can sometimes be biased or [consider fandom](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4558/48011), and I personally used YouTube videos in my answers (e.g. [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/64085/48011)), so it is fair that I ask this and have a generalized opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see a problem so long as the YouTube video doesn't become the answer in itself, just as long as it's relevant and you try to summarize the relevant part(s) in your answer in the event the video is taken down.

> **Provide context for links**
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be *helpful*, but avoid making it *necessary* to click on them as much as possible.

Source: [How do I write a good answer?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

But as you said, *"YouTubers can sometimes be biased"*, so it's always a good idea to look into the content creator and what their credentials are, e.g. a content creator who is actually a copyright attorney would be more of an authority on copyright law than someone who creates "reaction" streams of full anime episodes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a problem, provided that you do mention the source and preferably even a link to the video itself as well.

Many questions related to anime/manga, can or have already been answered in many YouTube videos. For example, at one point, there was someone who asked if Super Saiyan Blue Vegito is significantly weaker than Mastered Ultra Instinct Goku, as it was implied in the Super Dragon Ball Heroes anime.

This question isn't easy to answer, at all. It first requires a long explanation not why Super Dragon Ball Heroes is a spinoff with wildly different power scaling and why it has nothing to do with canon DBS. The second part of the answer was **even** more difficult which required answering whether canon MUI Goku is stronger than canon Vegito SSB in his appearance against Fusion Zamasu. This is a pretty difficult question to answer. However, all of these answers, already exist in YouTube videos. Especially the latter part, there are many credible Dragon Ball power scalers that tackle these questions and provide multiple possibilities as a valid answer.