# Resources to get started on the manga/anime universe v2

Tags: discussion

So we just got [the question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21936/6166) of a parent, wanting to offer manga to its child, who seemingly showed interest.

It made me look through the SE to find for a guide that would help a similar person where to start or how to start and I came across [this question](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/156/6166) (which I stole the question-title from btw). So it made me wonder whether we actually created such a recourse list? If so, where could it be found and if not, why did we not create such a list and whether it would still be relevant to make for cases as these?

Comment: We could have a similar page to the recommendations page - or just use that one

Comment: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/you-want-recommendations-heres-a-list-of-them - you could add a 'introductory anime' category